# Any possibility to centre the title within a toolbar?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, toolbar

I'm developing a little Android app written in Kotlin with the use of Jetpack.
I'm facing a little issue, I wanted to center my toolbar title but I didn't manage to figure out how. I saw that some recommend using a custom toolbar layout, but doing that isn't possible for me as I want my first page to be named "Grateful", and the second page named "Details" without having any code like

```
toolbar.setTitle("Details")
```

I already tried to set layout_gravity and gravity and all those things on the toolbar layout or even the appbar. But without any success.

Here is my actual layout for my main_Activity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearanceH5"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_notes_nav_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_notes"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using the Navigation library shipped by Google with their Jetpack Dev kit.

Thanks!

Comment: check my comment and replace it with your  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `XML` you can use custom `toolbar`

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarlin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTittle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:maxWidth="150dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And dont forget to change your activity theme to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: That's working for the first page where I want my title to be "Grateful".
But on the second page the grateful is staying. And I can't access to my toolbar as it's in my mainActivity and if I want to change it, it's from a fragment.

In fact with the navigation library, there is no need of defining the android:text. I mean you don't have to hardcode this as it's dynamically changed and use the label defined in my navigation graph.

Comment: you can control to use 1 main tool bar for whole app or each activity to have different toolbar thats up to you

Comment: Try to create new XML layout put toolbar in it and than call it with  <include
            android:id="@+id/mainBar"
            layout="@layoutapp_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: ya if your app have 1 main activity and you replace fragments on top of the activity, you can send broadcast everytime you visit new page to change the title , or make static method and call it from anywhere but i dont recommend using static when it come to the view

Comment: Toolbar toolbar = binding.appBar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbarTittle = binding.appBar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTittle); and than use this method   public void setTittle(String tittle) {
        toolbarTittle.setText(tittle);
    }  that you can call from anywhere

Comment: I will try it !

Comment: So doing like you said cause some issue.
If I use toolbarTitle from my fragment ofc it returns "must not be null"
If I define toolbarTitle in mainActivity and use a method to change the title on it that cause property toolbarTitle has not been initialized even if the toolbarTitle is initialized in the onCreate function of the main activity.

Comment: if you change this method to static you can call it this way MainActivity.setTittle(""); or use broadcast